# QGIS saves Eastings and Northings as 0, despite displaying correct coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, attribute-table

A point layer in a geopackage contains **easting** `format_number($x,0)` and **northing** `format_number($y,0)` fields to record co-ordinates.

The CRS for the project and the layer are set to BNG. When creating a feature, co-ordinates are accurately recorded, however both easting and northing change to **0** when updates to the layer are saved.

**QGIS version 3.4.6**

[image: Feature attributes prompted when creating a feature]

[image: Feature attributes after saving a feature]

Comment: Are you allowed to share the geopackage file? That would make it easier to figure out the problem, even if I guess it could be due to how the fields were defined.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-Sb8GvJYj9j

Comment: The behavior you describe is similar to what happens when you try to store text in a numerical field. What format are the easting and northing fields in? Make sure they're in a numerical format at least 6 digits long, or in text format at least 6 characters long.

Comment: They are in numerical format and I am assuming the length restriction is not an issue as this is a geopackage?

Answer (score 1):

Importing the file you shared:

1. add points
2. edit the table, selecting for example the `easting` filed
3. enter the formula `format_number($x,0)`
4. `Update all`
5. Exit edit mode, thus saving

The files retains the updated coordinates.

However,  since you mention that *"co-ordinates are accurately recorded"* I guess you originally had a *virtual* field.

Just to make sure, I created a virtual field, assigning `format_number($x,0)` as calculated value, saved the (`.gpkg`) file, created a new project, imported the `.gpkg`.
As expected, the virtual field was gone.

So this is also not your case, because you state the fields (`easting` and `northing`) are there, but zeroed-out.

(And this should have been a comment, not an answer ;) )

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Raf. It's the first time I have come across this so I'll probably log this as a bug if I find it repeating.